# Thumb scroller won't work, using slidersock jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, jquery-plugins

This is my current code, following pretty much the [specs](http://www.jqueryslidershock.com/?page_id=31):

```
<div id='my_carousel_ct' class='carousel-container'>  
      <div id="my_carousel_1" class="carousel slide">
            <!-- Carousel items -->
            <div id="my_carousel_2" class="carousel-inner rs-slider">
            <?php
                $Atargs = array(
                    'post_type'   => 'attachment',
                    'numberposts' => -1,
                    'post_status' => 'any',
                    'post_parent' => $post->ID/*,
                    'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id()*/
                );
                $attachments = get_posts( $Atargs );
                if ( $attachments ) {
                    $first = true;
                    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                        //echo '<li><img src="'.$attachment->guid.'"></li>';
                        $class = $first ? "active" : "";
                        echo '<div class="item '. $class .'">
                                    <div class="ts_border">
                                      <img src="'.$attachment->guid.'" alt="'.$attachment->alt.'" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
                        $first = false;
                    }
                }
            ?>
            </div>      
            <!-- Carousel nav -->
            <a class="carousel-custom" href="#my_carousel_1" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
            <a class="carousel-custom" href="#my_carousel_1" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>

            <div id="ts_scrol_1" class="ts_sld_scroller">
                  <ul>
                    <?php 
                        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                            $i = 0;
                            echo '<li>
                                      <a href="#" class="ts_refine_st" data-to="'.$i++.'" data-slideindex="'.$i.'">
                                        <img src="'.$attachment->guid.'" style="width:100px;height:60px;margin:0" height="60" width="100" alt="'.$attachment->guid.'" />
                                        </a>
                                    </li>';
                        }
                    ?>
                  </ul>
            </div>  
      </div>    
</div>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/css/slider_multiple.css' /> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri()?>/js/wpts_slider_multiple.js'></script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
     jQuery('#my_carousel_ct').tsSlider({
       thumbs:'bottom'
      , width:'475'
      , showText: true 
      , autoplay:5000
      , imgWidth: 100
      , imgHeight: 100
      , imgMarginTop: 0
      , imgMarginLeft: 0
      , squared: true 
      , textSquarePosition: 4 
      , textPosition: 'top'
      , imgAlignment: 'Center'
      , textColor: '999'
      , skin: 'transparent'
      , arrows:'ts-arrow-1'
      , sliderHeight: 400 
      , effects:''
    , titleBold: 'false'
    , titleItalic: 'false'
    , textBold: 'true' 
    , textItalic: 'false' 
    , textWidth: 90
      , background_sld:'#FFF'
      , background_caption:'#000'
     });        
  });
</script>
```

But this is how the scroller looks ([demo](http://toniweb.us/inmobiliaria/property/superb-house-title/))

[image]

I can't see any errors in the console

Also if I click on the thumb it doesn't jump to the related slide

Any idea what am I missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some of the things missing in thumbnails

Your code:

```
<a href="#" class="ts_refine_st" data-to="1" data-slideindex="1">   
  <img src="http://toniweb.us/inmobiliaria/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/DSC09549.jpg" style="width:100px;height:60px;margin:0" height="60" width="100" alt="http://toniweb.us/inmobiliaria/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/DSC09549.jpg">
</a>
```

Their code:

```
<a href="#" class="ts_refine_st" data-to="1" data-slideindex="0">
   <img src="http://www.jqueryslidershock.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/AssassinsCreedIII4-1024x640.jpg" height="60" width="100">
</a>
```

Difference is **data-to="1" data-slideindex="0"**
  - Which is getting incremented based on slides. **$i doesn't seem to be incremented, keep the $i= 0 before the foreach statement.**

Also the images

Your code:

```
<div class="item active" style="height: 250px; text-align: left; width: 100%;">
    <div class="ts_border" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">
          <img src="http://toniweb.us/inmobiliaria/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/DSC09502.jpg" alt="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;">
        </div>
```

Their code:

```
<li class="rs-slide-0" style="opacity: 0; height: 340px; text-align: left; width: 100%;">
    <div class="ts_border" id="">   
       <img src="http://www.jqueryslidershock.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/AssassinsCreedIII4-1024x640.jpg" width="100%" height="340" class="rs-slide-image" style="opacity: 1; width: 100%; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
       <div class="carousel-caption" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: auto;">
                        <h4>Fetch The Slider With Multiple Data Sources</h4>
                                    <p class="ts_txt" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
            Slidershock is very flexible, that means that you can show YouTube videos, Flickr Images, Instagram images, images taken from a RSS feed.&nbsp;You can also fetch the slider with the content of a Twitter account.            </p>
     </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

**-- The class name of the container are unique and incremented like rs_slide_0, _1, _2 which is what pointing the thumbnail as I believe where as yours is "item".**

-- Update on 12/2/2014

1. Adding `, effects:'sliceH'` in the configuration will solve the issue with thumbnail and image linking. Try with other effects if you want, I tried `sliceH` instead of providing blank value
2. Thumbnails positioning 
     Add the class `ts_scr_bottom` to the  tag which will display all thumbnails correctly and also provide with to `<ul>` according to number of thumbnails

   `<div id="ts_scrol_1" class="ts_sld_scroller ts_scr_bottom">
     <ul style="width:900px;">`

   Write some css to position it how you want it, check the demo.
3. For auto scrolling thumbnails - download plugin and include it after wpts_slider_multiple.js http://www.jqueryslidershock.com/wp-content/plugins/tsslider/js/jquery_autoscroll.js

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi there! Good catch the $li inside the foreach [...] About the increasing classes I can't see the it here: http://www.jqueryslidershock.com/?page_id=31 (Actually searching for "rs_slide_" won't return any results ) Any thoughts?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet As I gone through the code there,

Comment: But there's not any ocurrence of `class="rs-slide-0"` there, I'm confused :S

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet: Here is your fix:  
1. `, effects:'sliceH'` provide some effects try this `sliceH` instead of blank which will solve the thumbnail and image link issue, which will generate `rs-slide-0` classes automatically through JS

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet 2. Positioning Thubmnail..
`<div id="ts_scrol_1" class="ts_sld_scroller ts_scr_bottom">` add the class `ts_scr_bottom` which will display all other thumbnails and next provide width to `<ul>` according to your number of thumbnails `<ul style="width:900px;">`

Comment: 3. For auto scrolling thumbnails - download scrollable plugin with autoscroll and naviagation plugins and include it after wpts_slider_multiple.js from here http://www.jqueryslidershock.com/wp-content/plugins/tsslider/js/jquery_autoscroll.js